# Create Multiple pyds from one Project in Boost Python

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost-python

I have setup a Boost Python project that declares a python module. When the project is built it successfully creates the projectname.pyd and works great.

However it is one fairly big module, I would like the option to split it into several smaller pyds or sub modules.

Instead of Project.pyd I would like Foo.pyd, Bar.pyd and then would wrap them in a folder called Project with a **init**.pyd file to import them under the Project name like the following `from Project import Foo`. I basically want the exact structure this link describes.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/techniques.html#tutorial.techniques.creating_packages

This example makes it seem trivial. But no matter what it still builds and creates 1 pyd file. The example shows several pyd files being created. How do I get that same result?

I do not understand how Visual Studio can output more then 1 dll/pyd from a project file. I understand that I could make every single sub module its own project but that would get a excessive as I do not want hundreds of projects for each small namespace.

Is this possible in Boost Python? And if so how do I go about it?

tldr; I want to export multiple python .pyds from one C++ project.

Comment: Have you tried creating different projects within the solution, one for each different output (pyd file)?

Comment: But the example you gave relied on making different dlls, so that's what I thought you wanted.

Comment: I have an idea which involves creating the python namespace normally in subfolders, and having each of those python files import exactly what you want in that namespace from the one .pyd, but I don't have time to test it right now.

Comment: Sorry I dont think I explained that right, I want multiple pyds yes. But not multiple projects as it would quickly get out of hand. Your idea would work if only the names mattered. But we also hoped to have the option to hot swap out lower level pyds without replacing everything else in the hierarchy.

Comment: Makefile? Same thing, but you don't have to see them.

Comment: The Makefile would split it into separate projects and build them? That could work I suppose. The feeling I am getting is that this is not really the proper way to do things and thus unsupported. That is ok if it is the case, it is not a necessity.